# drupal multi-site symlinks?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, theming

So basically I am using a drupal multi-site.
Structure is as follows:

mywebsite.com:
 -- public_html/sites/default/

sub.mywebsite.com: -- public_html/sites/sub.mywebsite.com/

Works just fine(via settings.php), but the problem comes when theming. In order to reference valid image files, I must use `drupal_get_path('theme','mythemefolder')`
And due to having "pretty urls" activated, I must use the following code to reference the image files:

```
$uri=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$path=drupal_get_path('theme','mythemefolder')."/";
$real_prefix=$base_path; // global from drupal, equates to "/" as drupal resides in public_html folder.
$count=substr_count($uri,"/");
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) $real_prefix.="../";
```

In this way, I can do the following:

```
<script type="text/css">
#borderclass {
  background-image: url('<?= $real_prefix.$path.'images/a_border_image.png'; ?>');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  vertical-align: top;
}
</script>
<div class="borderclass" width="10px" height="10px"><!-- my image border div --></div>
```

It would be much preferable to not have to do this. And just simply reference the local site folder...

So that instead, I could write via PHP referenced above:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?= $path ?>images/a_border_image.png');"></div>
```

---

---

The resulting html should instead appear inside View Source, as:

```
<div style="background-image: url('themes/mythemefolder/images/a_border_image.png');"></div>
```

and Not:

```
<div style="background-image: url('sites/sub.mywebsite.com/themes/mythemefolder/images/a_border_image.png');"></div>
```

Is it possible to configure my server to do such a thing? Basically, I'd rather not have my clients even know that the "sites" directory exists on the server when using their own domain or subdomain. Let alone the above presented theming issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand what you are trying to understand, let me tell you that this is not how you usually deal with things.

A module does not need to look at the theme (except template files) folder to get anything. 
Logo, headers and other theme-related stuff can be stored in a theme's subfolder named "images" or anything else.

A theme folder will contain all template files (page template, html template, node template, etc) but a variable is ready for you if you want to get the theme's path.

url() in css, if the style is in a file, will be relative to the css file - not the current page. 
So that's where you can enter `url('images/a_border_image.png')` so it will be relative to the theme folder regardless of the theme's location. Browser is aware that the css file's location is `sites/sub.mywebsite.com/themes/mythemefolder` and your url() stuff in css will be relative to *that* folder.

However, in case you want to get the correct path (easily), do this:

```
<?php
$theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme','mythemefolder').'/';
$real_path = url($theme_path . 'images/images/a_border_image.png'); // 'sites/sub.mywebsite.com/themes/mythemefolder/images/a_border_image.png'
?>
```

[url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) will handle base path and all the substr stuff for you.

Comment: Totally understand. The only reason I am using the page.tpl.php (template) is for dynamically generating images using ImageTTF via php. That way I can cache them, and dynamically insert them in place of otherwise non-beautiful text.
But agreed, using the style.css file would be much more simple.


---------------------
Aside from that, the solution you have presented is definitely easier than mine. I will implement it. However my question was more in regards to apache symlinks. I would prefer to hide the /sites/mywebsite.com/ folder entirely from visibility in the source code. Is that possible